# How come it is possible to access variables without $this in the view?

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework2, scope

I started working with Zend Framework 2 a short while ago.

In the controller, I am sending variables to view using

```php
    return $viewmodel->setVariables(array(
                'exampleVariable' => 'exampleValue', 
                'exampleVariable2' => array(
                    'variableInArray' => $this->getMacAddress(),
                ),
    ));
```

In the view I was doing:

```php
$exampleVariable = $this->exampleVariable
// and 
$exampleVariable2 = $this->exampleVariable2
```

and then using those variable directly so I don't have to go through `$this` each time I use them.

I was working on it, and was modified a few stuff, and while I wanted to debug, I removed those two previous lines hoping it would break.

To my surprise, the `$exampleVariable` and `$exampleVariable2` were still available. At first, I thought it was a caching problem, but it turns out all the array keys that are sent to the view with `SetVariables()` can be accessed as variables.

My question is, how come it is possible to access them without `$this`?

<sub>I am probably gonna be warned about this, but this question if just for curiosity. I won't use the variables directly, as I prefer to create them in the view so I can comment them and add their respective variable types and stuff.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.0.2/modules/zend.view.php-renderer.scripts.html)

> Variables assigned to the view – either via a View Model, Variables container, or simply by passing an array of variables to render()– may be retrieved in three ways:

- Explicitly, by retrieving them from the Variables container composed in the PhpRenderer: $this->vars()->varname.
- As instance properties of the PhpRenderer instance: $this->varname. (In this situation, instance property access is simply proxying to the composed Variables instance.)
- As local PHP variables: $varname. The PhpRenderer extracts the members of the Variables container locally.

The explanation:

The PhpRenderer uses `extract` function to extract the variables into the function (render) scope. This allows to use `$exampleVariable` in the template. Further the PhpRenderer uses the magic `__get` function. So if you call `$this->exampleVariable` it looks in the data array directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the PHPRenderer class, specifically PHPRendered::render()

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PHPRenderer
```

You will see how the Views are generated, using extract (http://php.net/extract)

This allows any of the views variables to be accessed locally inside the view / template.